# React Bootstrap Custom Component Overflowing Column

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a custom toggle dropdown:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const DateRange = props => (
  <div className="dropdown artesianDropdownContanier">
    <div className="btn-group width100">
      <button type="button" className="btn dropdown-width">{props.selected}</button>
      <button type="button" className="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split artesianDropdownToggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <div className="dropdown-menu artesianDropdown">
        {props.dropDownValues.map(val => (
          <span
            key={val}
            value={val}
            className={`dropdown-item ${props.dropdownItemClass}`}
            onClick={() => props.onClick(val)}
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            {val}
          </span>
        ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default DateRange;
```

Which looks like this on the page:

[image]

When I go to resize the webpage the arrow portion of the component spills out of its bootstrap container:

[image]

If I set display on the arrow to "none" you can see that the dropdown button itself with the text is resizing perfectly. It seems to be the dropdown arrow portion which is giving me trouble.

[image]

Any ideas on how to keep this guy firmly in his parent container?
Thanks!

Comment: Write Responsive media Query to increase/decrease font weight

Comment: So it's the font which is causing the issue? Essentially taking up space in the container?

Comment: yeah exactly @Paul

Comment: more of a css problem, can you post your css here?

Comment: Already set to 100%. I ended up using overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis but will investigate media query and font weight. But yes, it is the text which is causing the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this style to the component containing `{props.selected}`  :

```
<button
    type="button" 
    className="btn dropdown-width"
    style={{
       textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
       overflow: 'hidden'
    }}
>
{props.selected}
</button>
```

This should replace the end of the `{props.selected}` text by 3 dots and let the place to the dropdown button. (some adjustments may be needed depending on your `dropdown-width` class)